# "Ascoltare", "sentire", "vedere" per un brano di musica, uno spettacolo musicale o un concerto: quando usare un verbo o l'altro?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5579/707) ho scritto la frase

> Recentemente sono *andata ad ascoltare* il balletto Pulcinella di Igor Stravinskij in versione concerto

ma ho ricevuto questo commento:

> Un parlante nativo direbbe preferibilmente "andata a sentire", o molto più facilmente "andata a vedere". Meglio ancora: "sono stata a vedere".

Non mi è chiaro quando debba usare un verbo o l'altro con un brano di musica, uno spettacolo musicale o un concerto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

C'è [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1921/707) correlata a questa, ma è molto generica.

Comment: Come madrelingua sono interessato a vedere cosa salta fuori da questa discussione. Per ora sono d'accordo con il commento che hai ricevuto. Per me un concerto si va a "sentire" o "vedere" (anche se non c'è granché da *vedere*), ma la musica a casa mia, curiosamente, la "ascolto". È davvero strano, ma io andrei a "vedere" un concerto al Palasport mentre mio padre lo "sente" alla radio. Quando poi il concerto è finito, mio padre torna ad "ascoltare" la musica che passano alla radio. :)

Comment: Personalmente trovo lo “stata” di “sono stata a vedere” molto colloquiale. Cioè, qualcuno lo direbbe, qualcuno no, e non tutti lo scriverebbero, rispetto ad “andata”.

Comment: Un balletto si vede, non si ascolta, a meno che tu non ti riferisca in particolare alle musiche del balletto. Un concerto si vede e si ascolta. Se di musica classica direi che si ascolta, se di Vasco Rossi o dei Pink  Floyd si vede anche. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ascoltare+un+balletto%2Cvedere+un+balletto%2C+ascoltare+un+concerto%2C+vedere+un+concerto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvedere%20un%20balletto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cascoltare%20un%20concerto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvedere%20un%20concerto%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sentire non mi piace, è più informale rispetto ad ascoltare soprattutto se si parla si musica classica. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ascoltare+un+concerto%2Csentire+un+concerto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cascoltare%20un%20concerto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csentire%20un%20concerto%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61: Ma si trattava del balletto in versione concerto: non c'era "niente" da vedere.

Comment: @Charo - scusa, allora sì, come dicevo nel mio commento.

Comment: Sono recentemente andato a vedere un concerto a Milano. Questo è quello che direi spiegando cosa ho fatto il mese scorso. In generale sono d'accordo con gd1 riguardo all'uso di vedere, sentire e ascoltare anche se userei di preferenza "ascoltare" anche per la radio.

Comment: Io per un concerto avrei usato "andare a sentire", soprattutto se non c'è niente da vedere. Comunque anche "andare ad ascoltare" pare che sia abbastanza diffuso, anche se mi sembra meno in contesto musicale e più nel senso di andare ad ascoltare un discorso.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=andare+ad+ascoltare%2Candare+a+sentire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Candare%20ad%20ascoltare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Candare%20a%20sentire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Candare%20ad%20ascoltare%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Candare%20a%20sentire%3B%2Cc1

Comment: @Enucatl - è curioso come a me i due verbi suggeriscano l'uso opposto, ossia: *ascoltare della musica e sentire un discorso.*

Comment: @Josh61 "ascoltare della musica" è sicuramente legittimo.

Comment: @Enucatl - sono sfumature  che non  hanno una vera risposta. È interessante comunque parlarne.

Comment: @Charo: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5367/ci-andiamo-a-vedere-un-film

Comment: @Josh61: diresti "sto sentendo il discorso del Presidente della Repubblica" o "sto ascoltando il discorso del Presidente della Repubblica"?

Answer (score 2):

Ci provo a cominciare con un argomento a contrario.

Nel 1835 Michele Ponza [ha criticato](https://books.google.se/books?id=JttCb4GHLqsC&lpg=PA38&ots=PzV0MT7Vjb&pg=PA38#v=onepage&f=false) Tommaso Grossi per aver usato l'espressione *sentire messa* nel suo romanzo "Marco Visconti":

> "Sentire la messa" è modo di dialetto: la messa si ode, si ascolta, alla messa si assiste.

L'argomento qui è che la gente non va a messa per godersi, passare una bella mattina, magari con un po' di musica d'organo e i cantanti a capella, e chiacchierare con i vicini. Si intende (almeno in teoria) l'ascoltazione, la partecipazione, la massima attenzione dalla parte di ognuno presente.

Più o meno lo stesso dice il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ascoltare-finestra-di-approfondimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> Ascoltare è intercambiabile con sentire, di cui **spesso rappresenta un sinonimo di grado più intenso («prestare attenzione a ciò che si percepisce con l’udito»)**. E dunque si può *ascoltare o sentire, la radio, una canzone, una discussione*, ecc., ma in genere ***ascoltare* implica un maggior coinvolgimento del soggetto rispetto a *sentire*.** <...> Ancora più specifico è ascoltazione, che si riferisce all’ascolto concentrato da parte di un professionista: l’ascoltazione di un brano musicale da parte di un musicista o di un fonico.

In caso di un concerto, uno spettacolo, o un brano musicale, quindi, vanno bene sia *sentire*, sia *ascoltare*, ma il significato può essere diverso, per es.:

- *Sono andata a sentire un concerto*: ho avuto un bel tempo, la musica mi è piaciuta tantissimo, mi sono goduta al massimo questa esperienza.
- *Sono andata ad ascoltare un concerto*: sono stata a sentire molto attentamente, perché ci sono interpretazioni diverse di questa opera e volevo fare un paragone con la mia interpretazione preferita, perché il fagotto di qualsiasi orchestra sbaglia sempre nel secondo atto, perché sono un biografo di Igor Stravinskij e cerco di capir meglio il suo carattere ascoltando la sua musica.

Come hanno detto gd1 e Josh61, quando c'è qualcosa da vedere (come un balletto, un spettacolo, un film), andrebbe meglio *sono andata a vedere*  che *sono andata a sentire*, se si sottintende la stessa "piacevole esperienza". E quando qualcuno *ascolta la musica* a casa, generalmente sceglie secondo i suoi gusti la melodia, il/la cantante, le parole, il genere musicale - cioè presta sempre attenzione a quello che suona, forse anche canta insieme a questa musica.